# How to get a list (from shell) of Icon Themes installed?

Tags: scripts, gsettings, icon-themes

I'm developing a simple script for change the icon theme with Unity.

How could I know all the current (Ubuntu & Unity) System **Icon** **Themes** with a shell command?

There are a few folders in `/usr/share/icons`, but I'm thinking that those folders are not all of them an Icon Themes.

Looking into the [code of Ubuntu Tweak](https://github.com/tualatrix/ubuntu-tweak/blob/master/ubuntutweak/tweaks/theme.py) I saw this function:

```
def _get_valid_icon_themes(self):
    # This function is taken from gnome-tweak-tool
    dirs = ( '/usr/share/icons',
    os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".icons"))
    valid = walk_directories(dirs, lambda d:
    os.path.isdir(d) and \
    not os.path.exists(os.path.join(d, "cursors"))
```

Then, I'm thinking the Icon Themes are all the folders in /usr/share/icons without a `cursors` folder inside?

Which command could I use for get a list of themes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you men someting like that? `ls -I "*.*" /usr/share/icons`

Comment: Thanks, but you're not checking the "cursors" inside :O In other way, I'm not sure about which directories are the "really" Icon Themes.

Comment: I believe, if there were an api for fetching icon themes, unity-tweak-tool devs would use it. Maybe it's the only way